# reading input from ifstream as doubles and performing calculations with them c++

Tags: c++

I have been working on this project for a while now where we use `ifstream` to read input from a text file. The text file contains an array of doubles (each is supposed to represent the resistance of a circuit):

> ```
> 1 1 1
> 0.5 0.5 1
> 2 3 1
> ```

for example. The program is supposed to read in a series of three of these doubles and calculate the total resistance `(1/(1/R1+1/R2+1/R3))`. My question is how I can read these in as doubles. I know how to read them in as a string and have written some code that I though should work (but clearly doesn't). If you could point me in the right direction and give me a little help, it would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

My code: (be nice)

```
int main()
{
    ifstream in("input.txt");
    vector<vector<string>> data;
    string resistors;
    while (in)
    {
        if (!getline(in, resistors))
            break;
        istringstream line(resistors);
        vector<string> record;
        while (line)
        {
            if (!getline(line, resistors, ','));
            break;
            record.push_back(resistors);
        }
        string totalResistance;
        for (int c = 0; c < resistors.length(); c += 3)
        {
            totalResistance += 1 / ((1 / resistors[c]) + (1 / resistors[c + 1]) + (1 / resistors[c + 2]));
        }
        cout << totalResistance << endl;
        data.push_back(record);
    }
    if (!in.eof())
    {
        cerr << "STOP!" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a lot of information missing from this question. For example, how the input is formatted in the file you are reading from? Do you want to read strings from the file or you want to read doubles? Is each input value separated by newline, or everything is available in a single line?

Comment: Sorry about that, the inputted is formatted as a nx3 array of doubles where each double is separate by a space. I want to read the input in as a double. Basically, each row represents a series of resistors of a circuit and I want to calculate the total resistance for each row. I want it to be inputed as a double and returned as a double. Each new resistance should be outputed on its own line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
ifstream input;
input.open("filename", ios::in);
double value_1 = 0, value_2 = 0, value_3 = 0;
input >> value_1 >> value_2 >> value_3;
```

This is the simplest way you can use to read three values separated by space. A slightly complicated way would be if you want to read line after line. In that case you need to get sub strings that can separate double values.

```
ifstream input;
input.open("filename", ios::in);
while (!input.eof())
{
     double values[3];
     string delimiter = " ", token, line;
     size_t pos, index = 0;
     getline(input, line);
     while ((pos = line.find(delimiter)) != std::string::npos) 
     {
         token = line.substr(0, pos);
         istringstream i(token);
         i >> values[index++];
         line.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
     }
     istringstream i(line);
     i >> values[index];

}
```

I haven't executed the code, I expect it to work. Please include necessary header files.

Comment: How could I make that loop through every element in the input file? What if I wanted to use different files for input where I didn't know how many rows it would have?

Comment: Thank you so much! I've only been learning this for a couple of weeks now so I really can't follow that though. Could you possibly walk me through that if you wouldn't mind?

Comment: If you want to have even more flexibility e.g. you don't know how many resisters there are in a single line, then instead of double array, you can use a double vector and keep adding data into vector.

Comment: I will start with the second while loop; the second while loop stops when variable `pos` becomes `-1`, which will be the case when it cannot find a delimiter `space`; i.e. for last double value.  
First value is stored in token as string and converted to double value using istringstream; the conversion takes place with the right shift operator. this value is then erased from the line and the loop continues for the second value.

Comment: For the last value the space delimiter is not found. So this last value is converted to double like before but outside the loop. If you are okay with the answer, don't forget to accept it.

Comment: Okay, thank you! That makes perfect sense. Could I then add to the while loop code to calculate the total resistance and output that to a separate string of doubles? And I will, don't worry.

Comment: At the end of the second while loop; after the third value is converted to double, you can do your calculations. The amount of complexity depends on you. You can also add this data into a 2-dimensional vector; and once all the data is read from the file you can start another nested loop for calculations. Since you are the programming this, you should make a decision as you see fit.

Comment: When compiling, it lists the 's' from 's.find' as an undeclared identifier, why is this?

Comment: I edited the code for mistakes; I guess you can see the edited code now.

Comment: Okay thank you. I'm going to be honest, I have no idea where the values are being stored nor do I have any clue how to call individual values...